# Framer Motion layout animation not working on alignItems

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I am currently working on a personal project that has a notification implementation.
This notification has to be able to expand and set the title-text from alignItems: "center" to alignItems: "start"
I am using the motion.div prop layout in order to support layout animations, yet this does not seem to work.
There is no animation regarding the alignItems, it just immediately snaps to "center" or "start".
Does anyone else had this problem and know a solution?

A video demonstrating the issue:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRrKZGKW2ok

this is the Notification component

```js
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { isMobile } from "react-device-detect";

type NotificationProps = {
  text: string;
  subtext?: string;
  type: string;
};

export default function Notification(props: NotificationProps) {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
  let defaultClassnames =
    "fixed rounded-xl text-white flex justify-between m-[1.25vh] flex flex-row ";
  defaultClassnames +=
    props.type === "SUCCESS"
      ? "bg-green-500 "
      : props.type === "WARNING"
      ? "bg-yellow-500 "
      : props.type === "ERROR"
      ? "bg-red-700 "
      : props.type === "INFO"
      ? "bg-blue-500 "
      : "bg-gray-500 ";

  const variants = {
    expanded: {
      alignItems: "start",
      width: isMobile ? "95vw" : "",
      height: isMobile ? "70vh" : "",
      top: isMobile ? "4.3rem" : "",
      left: isMobile ? "0" : "",
      bottom: isMobile ? "auto" : "",
      right: isMobile ? "auto" : "",
    },
    collapsed: {
      alignItems: "center",
      width: isMobile ? "15rem" : "20rem",
      height: "4rem",
      top: isMobile ? "0" : "auto",
      left: isMobile ? "0" : "auto",
      bottom: isMobile ? "auto" : "0",
      right: isMobile ? "auto" : "0",
    },
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
      className={defaultClassnames}
      variants={variants}
      initial="collapsed"
      animate={expanded ? "expanded" : "collapsed"}
      layout
    >
      <div className={`pl-2 ${expanded && "pt-4"}`}>{props.text}</div>
      <div
        className={`flex items-center ${isMobile ? "gap-6" : "gap-4"} ${
          expanded && "pt-4"
        }`}
      >
        {props.subtext && (
          <div>
            <motion.svg
              className="cursor-pointer"
              onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}
              initial={{ scale: 1.8, rotate: isMobile ? 180 : 0 }}
              width="19"
              height="19"
              viewBox="0 0 19 19"
              fill="none"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <motion.path
                d="M6.18275 17.4166H12.8169C15.6986 17.4166 17.4165 15.6987 17.4165 12.817V6.19079C17.4165 3.30121 15.6986 1.58329 12.8169 1.58329L6.19067 1.58329C3.309 1.58329 1.59109 3.30121 1.59109 6.18288L1.59109 12.817C1.58317 15.6987 3.30109 17.4166 6.18275 17.4166ZM6.28567 10.157L9.08025 7.36246C9.199 7.24371 9.34942 7.18829 9.49984 7.18829C9.65025 7.18829 9.80067 7.24371 9.91942 7.36246L12.714 10.157C12.9436 10.3866 12.9436 10.7666 12.714 10.9962C12.4844 11.2258 12.1044 11.2258 11.8748 10.9962L9.49984 8.62121L7.12484 10.9962C6.89525 11.2258 6.51525 11.2258 6.28567 10.9962C6.05609 10.7666 6.05609 10.3945 6.28567 10.157Z"
                fill="#F3F3F3"
              />
            </motion.svg>
          </div>
        )}
        <div className="mr-2 pr-2">
          <motion.svg
            className="cursor-pointer"
            initial={{ scale: 1.8 }}
            width="24"
            height="24"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <motion.path
              d="M16.19 2H7.81C4.17 2 2 4.17 2 7.81V16.18C2 19.83 4.17 22 7.81 22H16.18C19.82 22 21.99 19.83 21.99 16.19V7.81C22 4.17 19.83 2 16.19 2ZM15.36 14.3C15.65 14.59 15.65 15.07 15.36 15.36C15.21 15.51 15.02 15.58 14.83 15.58C14.64 15.58 14.45 15.51 14.3 15.36L12 13.06L9.7 15.36C9.55 15.51 9.36 15.58 9.17 15.58C8.98 15.58 8.79 15.51 8.64 15.36C8.35 15.07 8.35 14.59 8.64 14.3L10.94 12L8.64 9.7C8.35 9.41 8.35 8.93 8.64 8.64C8.93 8.35 9.41 8.35 9.7 8.64L12 10.94L14.3 8.64C14.59 8.35 15.07 8.35 15.36 8.64C15.65 8.93 15.65 9.41 15.36 9.7L13.06 12L15.36 14.3Z"
              fill="#F3F3F3"
            />
          </motion.svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance!